# After cloning my HDD to SSD I can't select the SSD to boot from

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clone

I am trying to migrate my windows 10 OS to my SSD for the usual reasons. I've been following the EaseUS tutorial and I've managed to clone my HDD to my SSD (using easeUS TODO software). The problem I am facing is that I can't select the SSD to boot from.

I've tried using the Windows Boot Options menu, but I never get the "Use another operating system" option. None of the other methods for setting the boot media recognize the SSD as something to boot from.

How can I get my pc to recognize the SSD? Or is there a better tool to do this migration?

Comment: Is SSD seen in BIOS & Boot Order? What happens if you select it? Does it boot into old Windows 10 or throws some error or does nothing?  Is it UEFI or MBR boot? If UEFI, did you select EFI Partition apart from C Drive for cloning? Also check if anything in this post is relevant to your situation https://superuser.com/questions/1535225/windows-will-not-boot-from-new-ssd#comment2329237_1535225

Comment: SSD is not seen in BIOS or Boot Order. It (and the HDD it is cloned from) is UEFI. I cloned literally everything on the old HDD, EFI partition included. I'm going to take a look at that answer and see.

Comment: The EaseUS tool should have taken care of it. I've used it in the past and it seemed fine. Are you sure the tutorial you followed included making the new clone bootable? They also have other cloning options that are just for making backups.

Comment: [This](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/how-to-install-an-ssd-without-reinstalling-windows.html) is the tutorial I was following, and it didn't say to do anything special to make it bootable. I've cleaned the SSD and I'm currently re-cloning to it using Macrium Reflect like in the linked Q, so in a few hours I'll try those steps and we'll see.

Answer (score -1):

GreySage looks to have solved this using my solution here to a similar problem:

[Windows will not boot from new SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1535225/windows-will-not-boot-from-new-ssd)

Comment: If another question has an answer, that answers this question, then this question should be flagged as a duplicate.  Why wasn't this question flagged as a duplicate?  Considering you wrote the other answer, submitting another answer to solely link to another one of your answers, is frowned upon.  I have used my gold badge in the Windows 10 tag to close this question as a duplicate.  It would be appreciated if you don't submit other answers, that only contain links, to other answers.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't mean it and I wasn't trying to toot my own horn. I found this after looking at GreySages comment on mine and thought it would help someone else who stumbled across this question since the two aren't exact duplicates.

Comment: The author of this question indicated the answer to the duplicate solved this problem.  Which is great but in the future flag as a duplicate instead of submitting an answer with only a link to another answer (no matter who is the author)